# How can I identify what is preventing my HDDs from suspending?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ubuntu-20.04, suspend, powersave

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 20.04 with HWE.
I have two HDDs installed and those never go to sleep even if their usage is none for 5+ minutes (that's the setting in *gnome* *Disks* manager).

This used to work some time ago, but now doesn't seem to.
If I manually put both disks to sleep, those stay as such for hours, so not quite sure what's preventing this from happening.

How can I find this out?

Thanks!

**Edit**

`fuser` and/or `lsof` don't report of any file open on those mounts (i.e. `/disk2` and `/disk6`) - I've set the timer to 5 minutes, from 10 and I'll report what happens.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366438/hard-disk-not-going-to-standby-automatically) for possible causes.

Comment: my _smartd_ should be setup with default values (30 mins) and my disks are supposed to shutdown in 5 minutes of not being active. Checked the _-B_ option and those don't support *APM*, not sure how to check _-S_ via command line, but via Ubuntu UI it's 5 minutes... so not sure what's the issue.

Comment: Does this happen if you just disable `smartd`?

Comment: I issued `sudo smartd stop`  and waited approx 3 hours. The disks are still _active/idle_. Should I have used another command to stop _smartd_?

Comment: Try `service smartd stop`.

Comment: Sorry that's what I did `service smartd stop` mistyped in comment before. Ubuntu then prompts for sudo password etc etc, and then I checked the status and the service is actually stopped.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594548/17660) for `pvestatd`. Question: Are these disks internal?

Comment: I don't think I'm running`pvestatd`. Yes, disks are internal.

Comment: For tracing perhaps [fatrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fatrace.1.html) or [auditd](https://serverfault.com/a/834902/18736).  The cause can nowadays be [udisks2](https://petermolnar.net/article/hard-drive-spindown-clicking-noise/) rather than smartd. If nothing works, [this](http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/hardware/why-some-hard-disks-wont-spin-down-hdparm) might help.

Comment: Check the config files in `udisks2` and indeed I already have those for the two HDDs with the same parameters I set in ubuntu disks UI (i.e. 60 - 5 minutes), still those don't spin down. hdparm -B option is not supported by my drives, so not sure what else to do. Feels like to OS doesn't spin them down but I have to do manually?

Comment: Are the two disks the same model? It might be that your Linux has some incompatibility with the disk firmware.

Comment: @harrymc I'm starting to thinking the same... I've temporarily disabled `udisks2` as per your suggestion - let's see if that solves it...

Comment: Even stopping `udisks2` didn't help - may be that these disks are incompatible with the command to _timer standby_... and Linux perhaps? Those are both `WD40EZRX` I think [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1899361) is what is afflicting me too perhaps...

Comment: This bug-report has a workaround at the end which you may test, but if it doesn't help then it's not the same. Trivia: Your bug-report actually started [in 2014](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1281588) (!), so see if it adds something (especially since your disks are mentioned). These disks seem to be very old, so perhaps modern Linux has troubles piloting them.

Comment: @harrymc Upon restarting `udisks2`, I could see in the status that it issued the command to the disks to sleep after 5 minutes of being idle... and guess what, they went to sleep. Could it be possible that upon startup something like `smartd` would override the `udisks2` directive to put the disks to sleep? `smartd` is running every 30 mins and hasn't woken up the sleeping disks as per setup...

Comment: It might be a timing/racing problem between `udisks2` and `smartd`?

Comment: Not sure if it's the timing issue - because now both daemons are running and the disks have been on _standby_ for 30+ minute. `smartd` is supposed to check every 30 mins, the disks are supposed to spin down after 5. Could it be more an issue if upon startup `smartd` overrides the _hdparm_ command to sleep the disks every 5 minutes? Would `smartd` also try to control such HDD parameters? Point is, restarting `udisks2` seems to have applied the timed _standby_ command just fine, I wonder if upon starting he system some other daemon resets what set by `udisks2`? Will spin disks and test again.

Comment: If it's a matter of timing that can be solved by restarting `udisks2`, a simple `cron` job can fix it.

Comment: I think I may need to audit to understand more... wasn't able to reproduce

Comment: @harrymc I installed run the audit daemon (`sudo apt install auditd`, then setup the audit on disks `sudo auditctl -w /dev/sda -p rwa`), can clearly see that unfortunately _udisksd_ (part of _udisks2_) is the culprit which queries the disks every 10 mins and prevents from sleeping. It's also the utility that controls the disks and sets them to sleep... and quite embedded in Ubuntu. I hope they fix the _udisksd_ [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1899361) asap. Please write an answer along these lines with detailed explanation and I'll upvote.

Comment: Unfortunately, only you, the person that did the digging, can do a detailed explanation of what you found.

Comment: I guess I'll have to write an answer myself then. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart monitoring the filesystem with obvious tools such as `fuser` and `lsof`, the only tool which actually reports every activity is [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) (installing then issuing `sudo auditctl -w /dev/sda -p rwa` and then searching the logs with `sudo ausearch -f /dev/sda`).

With this powerful tool, one is able to clearly identify what is interacting with the given device (`/dev/sda` in this example) and then take appropriate actions.

In my case it's the combination of having a couple of WD disks which apparently don't play nice with with *standby* command and are woken up by the *udisks2/udisksd* daemon invoking the smart report command every 10 minutes (it shouldn't wake up the disk - or better preventing from *standby*-ing but it does with those WD [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1281588) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1899361) for more details).